# How to use class from blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created class `Helper` with path `App\Http\Helpers\`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Helpers;

class Helper 
{
    public static function applyClass($user) {
        return "new";
    }

}
```

Then I have registered it in `app.php` in section `aliases`:

```
'Helper' =>   App\Http\Helpers\Helper::class
```

When I tried to call static method from blade:

```
<tr class="{{ \Helper::applyClass($user) }}">
<tr class="{{ Helper::applyClass($user) }}">
```

I get an error:

```
Class 'Helper' not found
```

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: take a look at blade service injection https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#service-injection

Comment: Injection is not required when calling static methods.

Comment: I tried: `composer dump-autoload` no result

Comment: Sorry, took me a bit to write everything down. :)

Comment: @user3573738, you don't need to add any aliases. See my answer. It is tested on my machine and it works

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is not how facades work. A custom facade is required to extend `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade`, which basically only requires the custom facade to implement `protected static function getFacadeAccessor()`. This method should return the name (or a class or an interface) which is supposed to be resolved by the facade.

A facade allows you to call instance methods (i.e. non-`static` methods) in a static way. This works because facades know how to redirect calls to static methods to the instance behind the facade. This is done by implementing `__callStatic($method, $args)`, which simply redirects the static method call to the implementation of which the name is returned by `getFacadeAccessor()`.

Imagine you have a service registered under the name `helper` in the service container. You could then execute a method `getColor()` on it using `app('helper')->getColor()` or `app()->make('helper')->getColor()`.

With a facade called `Helper` which resolves your `helper` by returning it as string from the `getFacadeAccessor()` method, you can then perform the same action using `Helper::getColor()`.

---

In your case, you have a few options now:

**1) Using a class with static methods:**

Similarly to what you already did, you can define a class with static methods. You then call these methods statically from your blade view by using the fully qualified class name (FQCN):

```
// app/Helpers/Helper.php
class Helper
{
    public static function getColor(): string
    {
        return 'blue';
    }
}

// resources/views/some/page.blade.php
<div style="color:{{ \App\Helpers\Helper::getColor() }}"> ... </div>
```

**2) Using a non-static class with a facade:**

You can use a similar class as above with non-static methods and add a facade for it:

```
// app/Helpers/Helper.php
class Helper
{
    public function getColor(): string
    {
        return 'blue';
    }
}

// app/Facades/Helper.php
class Helper extends \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return \App\Helpers\Helper::class;
    }
}

// config/app.php -> 'aliases' array
[
    // ... other facades ...
    'Helper' => \App\Facades\Helper::class,
]

// resources/views/some/page.blade.php
<div style="color:{{ \Helper::getColor() }}"> ... </div>
```

**3) Using a global non-class helper file:**

You can also define a basic PHP file containing some helper functions, which are registered globally. These functions are not class methods and do therefore not require being called with a class prefix:

```
// app/Helpers/color_utils.php
if (!function_exists('get_color')) {
    function get_color()
    {
        return 'blue';
    }
}

// app/Providers/HelperServiceProvider.php
class HelperServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(): void
    {
        $filenames = glob(app_path('Helpers/*.php'));

        if ($filenames !== false && is_iterable($filenames)) {
            foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
                require_once $filename;
            }
        }
    }
}

// config/app.php -> 'providers' array
[
    // ... other providers ...
    \App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider::class,
]

// resources/views/some/page.blade.php
<div style="color:{{ get_color() }}"> ... </div>
```

**4) Using a class and service injection:**

Also a nice option is to inject a service into a Blade template using the service container. Laravel provides a Blade directive called `@inject($var, $fqdn)` for it.

```
// app/Helpers/Helper.php
class Helper
{
    public static function getColor(): string
    {
        return 'blue';
    }
}

// resources/views/some/page.blade.php
@inject('helper', \App\Helpers\Helper::class)

<div style="color:{{ $helper->getColor() }}"> ... </div>
```

I hope the code speaks for itself. Namespaces of the files are omitted on purpose, of course you should use the namespaces according to the directories (PSR-4 compliant).

If you don't need any dependencies and you basically only need static access to something, I personally prefer global helpers (option 3).

Comment: This is The Answer, good explanation, it should be accepted blindfolded. I am missing a double upvote.

Comment: Yes, "this is not how facades work" but OP was not trying to create a facade, just a class alias. Their method works fine, likely they were experiencing caching issues or something. Using an alias entry is the same as setting a class alias with the `use` statement. The fact that most of built-in aliases are facades is just a coincidence. See for example `Illuminate\Support\Str`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Just a note for the option 2: in Laravel 8, you will need to change the method to : ```protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return \App\Helpers\Helper::class;
    }```

Comment: @DAMIENJIANG Good spot. In fact, it has been this way all the time and my answer was wrong. Fixed it right away, thanks.

Comment: Better explained as Laravel Docs! Thanks for this approach!

Comment: how to add a new Provider aliases in laravel 11?... any idea?

Comment: @iohansandoval I think they removed it from the project template, but you can still add it back. See [`config/app.php` source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/50124befd6977b3dfcd3143624c7bf82a9db2d13/config/app.php#L175-L188) for details.

Comment: thanks @Namoshek , It works like Laravel 10, just add to array in config/app.php  'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
        // 'Example' => App\Facades\Example::class, ])->toArray(),

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this in a straight forward way by following these steps.

**Step 1**

Create your class file in your desired path (example: `app/Helpers/Helper.php`) and define the class

```php
<?php

class Helper 
{
    public static function applyClass($user) {
        return "call from helper to " . $user;
    }

}
```

**Step 2**

Modify `composer.json` file by adding your file within the entry of the `autoload` key

```php
"autoload": {
    "prs-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/Helper.php"
    ]
}
```

Note that you are not changing anything apart from including this entry: `"files": ["app/Helpers/Helper.php"]`.
Save the file.

**Step 3**

Run this command from your root directory:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

it refreshes the autoload cache.

**Step 4**

You can now use your class from anywhere including blade

```
<tr class="{{ Helper::applyClass("user") }}">
```

This way, you can also create global functions as well.

Answer (score 0):

While the other solutions work pretty fine (such as inject directive), do you think it's a good practice to access a service from a blade page? I think you needed to do so because the controller or the service did not provide the necessary information to the blade. So, it would be not a bad idea to go back to controller and send what information the blade page needs to it.