# Called Package and use in Blade Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to called function from package in laravel blade, I have a controller and when I called index Controller all is good.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use charlieuki\ReceiptPrinter\ReceiptPrinter as ReceiptPrinter;

class ShipingLabelController extends Controller
{
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // Init printer
        $printer = new ReceiptPrinter;
        $printer->init(
            config('receiptprinter.connector_type'),
            config('receiptprinter.connector_descriptor')
        );
        $printer->printReceipt();
    }

}
```

and then i Want To called all the package in Blade and run some function from the packege in my blade. This is my blade

```
@inject('ReceiptPrinter', \charlieuki\ReceiptPrinter\ReceiptPrinter::class)
@inject('FilePrintConnector', \Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector::class)
@inject('Printer', \Mike42\Escpos\Printer::class)



<div>
    @php
         $printer = new ReceiptPrinter;
         $printer->init(
                        "network",
                        "192.168.8.102"
                       );
         $printer->printReceipt();
    @endphp
  </div>
```

but i get this error

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [charlieuki\ReceiptPrinter\ReceiptPrinter::class] does not exist. (View: C:\laragon\www\work\freshboxfinal\resources\views\Print\shippinglable.blade.php)
```

Comment: you can pass the data of `$printer->printReceipt();` in your blade using a variable in your return statement from controller

Comment: what line is the error referring to, the first `@inject`?

Comment: You probably shouldn't name them _all_ `ReceiptPrinter`. Also, why do this in the view?

Comment: @lagbox line @inject('ReceiptPrinter', \charlieuki\ReceiptPrinter\ReceiptPrinter::class) error "Target class [charlieuki\ReceiptPrinter\ReceiptPrinter::class] does not exist. "

Comment: are you sure you did not put quotes around that second argument? as that error would mean somewhere you actually passed the string literal `'charlieuki\ReceiptPrinter\ReceiptPrinter::class'` instead of just `'charlieuki\ReceiptPrinter\ReceiptPrinter'`

Comment: @lagbox i followed this step https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57560226/how-to-use-class-from-blade-template